# Memory leak in async TCP server (Windows Service)

Tags: c#, asynchronous, tcp, server, async-await

i am doing my first steps with async/await in C# and for this purpose I wanted to write a simple TCP server that receives simple strings (for now).
So I set up a Windows service that contains a loop that is listening for incoming connections, accepts these connections and closes the socket (I am planning to write the strings to a log file or something, but this will have to wait until the issue I am about to describe is resolved).

Anyway, the problem is that after having received some strings over the network, my service is taking up memory which is not released later on. When I start the service and no connections are coming in, the process is taking 4.716K. This amount increases when connections are accepted (as I would have expected), but the resources seem not to be released afterwards...

Probably, I am overlooking something, but I can't find a solution (although the "project" consists of only few lines of code right now) so I would very much appreciate your help, guys :/

These are the startup/shutdown event handlers:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    this.listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 7777);
    this.listener.Start();

    this.worker = new Thread(StartServer);
    this.worker.Start();
}

protected override void OnStop(string[] args)
{
    this.serviceIsRunning = false;
    this.worker.Join();

    // TODO: Cancellation token maybe?
}
```

And this the server loop:

```
private async void ServerStart(object arguments)
{
    while (serviceIsRunning)
    {
        TcpClient client = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
        Task requestTask = HandleRequest(client);
    }

    this.listener.Stop();
}
```

The connection handler:

```
private async Task HandleRequest(TcpClient client)
{
    using (var stream = new StreamReader(client.GetStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        // Do something with it
        string request = await stream.ReadToEndAsync();
    }

    // Gracefully close connection
    client.Close();
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: 4.7KB (did you mean MB?) of used memory doesn't say much, given that the GC may decide its not worth the effort to run a collection. You could try to manually add `GC.Collect()` calls and see if memory is released, but you would be far better off profiling your app and seeing if there are any objects sitting around that are no longer used after manually forcing a collection (their reference tree goes all the way to the app root).

Answer (score 2):

The memory usage is pretty low.  I've seen the garbage collector wait until I have 2 gigabytes of memory consumed by 3d models / images before it will run.  If you watch the behavior of your application over time, you will see peaks and valleys over a large number of runs.  I suggest two experiments.

1. Start task manager, run your process at idle for a few seconds, then send some big bursts of data from the server so that the request is handled around 100-1000 times, then let it stay open for a few seconds and close it.  The memory usage should return to where it was before your app was opened.
2. Follow nearly the same procedure, but this time, call the garbage collector after the request is handled (GC.Collect()).  Check to see if your memory usage is different this time.

If this doesn't work as expected, try creating and destroying your TCP server class.  Memory usage should return to normal.  This isolate the problem to your class or the Garbage Collector.